# Query about applets in java

Tags: java, applet, awt

I am unable to understand why the println() statement inside paint() is executing twice.This is the code-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class FirstApplet extends Applet
{
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println(getBackground());
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("This is my first Applet",250,250);
        System.out.println(getBackground());
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
>
> java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=255]
>
> java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=255]

Can somebody please explain me why the println() inside paint() is executing twice?

Comment: This code `System.out.println(getBackground());` exists in `init()` and `paint(..)`method

Comment: @MaxZoom-The code is same as shown above.

Comment: It will execute whenever `paint()` executes. You don't know in advance how many times that will be.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);  // will trigger repaint()!
    setForeground(Color.RED);   // will trigger repaint()!
    g.drawString("This is my first Applet",250,250);
    System.out.println(getBackground());
}
```

The `paint(Graphics)` method is called whenever the toolkit feels it is necessary to do so.  There are many things that will cause a `repaint()` (which in turn, leads to a call to `paint(Graphics)`).  Some of them are:

- A window moves in front of, or is removed from in front of, the app.
- The size of the app. changes.
- The background or foreground color changes or a component state changes.
- A menu opens or closes.
- ...

Obviously, a paint **does not** happen only the times the programmer wants (or expects) it to.  If that 'paint whenever needed' is a problem for the app., it is the apps. problem to sort, not the toolkits.

---

Queries for you:

1. Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).
2. Why use AWT?   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.